# Top bar position problem in Internet Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, top-bar, internet-explorer

The top bar seem to behave strangely on Internet Explorer 11.

I got that display;

[image]

While on Firefox it look good;

[image]

In case it help to diagnose, it's from a Windows 10 laptop with a 1366 x 766 screen resolution.

When I scroll right in Internet Explorer it shows it that way, and the color code seems loss.

[image]

Comment: I think it's wider because there's some weird bug in footer (it becomes wider than it supposed to be on network sites, except SO). It makes topbar wider too I guess.. But anyway, we're investigating.

Comment: Fix: don't use IE.

Comment: Confirmed. Also with Windows 7 and IE 9. No issues with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Fixed for me today.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Hi, when I filled that bug report long time ago, it was corrected, you can see Takkat's comment. Could be tagged status-completed somehow I guess, as it was fixed, but no one answered there. (Now IE just no longer work and supported I understand)